# Example 10.36 Rudin

Tags: real-analysis

> **Example 10.36**
>
> Let $E= \Bbb R^{2}$-{$0$}, the plane with the origin removed. The $1$-form$$ \eta=\frac{xdy-ydx}{x^{2}+y^{2}}$$ is closed.
>
> Fix $r>0$, define $$ \gamma(t)=(r \cos t, r \sin t)$$
>   where $0\leq t \leq 2\pi$
>
> Then $\gamma$ is a curve (" an oriented 1-simplex") in $E$. Since $\gamma(0)= \gamma(2\pi)$, we have $\partial \gamma =0$

My question is, why $\gamma$ is an oriented $1$-simplex, and how we get $\partial \gamma =0$?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An oriented 1-simplex is, by definition, a continuous map $\gamma:[a,b]\to X$ for some topological space $X$. For such a map, we define the face-map by  $\partial \gamma=\gamma(b)-\gamma(a)$.